# Where are my OpenCV development libraries installed?

Tags: android-ndk

I am configuring CDT with Open Cv but i don't know where is the open cv include libraries are, when i open the c++ project properties and go to setting and then Tool Setting then it need include library but i don't know which path  i should give for open cv include library

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html

Comment: i am using the above tutorial for the setup

Comment: You are allowed to edit your own question by the way.

Comment: @A--C R you getting my point now? i have a problem in configuring CDT with OPEN CV.